# Chrome Remote-Debugging-Port Headless Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When i run chrome.exe --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=8989 in CMD, its running (DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:8989/devtools/browser/9fd740d1-c87a-4443-9e18-d972442af47f)

but i cant interact with like going to driver.get, why ya?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:8989")
chrome_options.add_argument('--remote-allow-origins=*')

# Start the WebDriver with Chrome options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# Example interaction with Chrome
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

print(driver.title)
```

WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:8989
from unknown error: unable to discover open pages
Stacktrace:

i want to interact with it with remote-debugging-port 8989

Comment: Make sure to install a WebDriver (Firefox, chrome, safari, or IE) and then add it to your PATH. You can find the list of the drivers under the **Drivers** section on this page: https://pypi.org/project/selenium/. I would recommend you to the https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase package that is much easier to use.